# Apache2 enable catch all virtual host

Tags: apache-2.4, centos8

I have Virtual Hosts enabled on my Apache2 server and every domain has its /etc/httpd/sites-available/domainX.conf and /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/domainX.conf symlink files like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domainX.com
    ServerAlias domainX.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainX/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/domainX.com/log/domainX.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/domainX.com/log/domainX-access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domainX [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domainX
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.domainX
    ServerAlias domainX
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainX/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/domainX/log/domainX-ssl-error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/domainX/log/domainX-ssl-access.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainX/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainX/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainX/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when visiting my IP it will show the content of one of my domains and I've learned that it uses the first configuration it finds - it makes sense as the listed domain is one that begins with an 'a'.

Now I've learned from [Apache2 disable catch all virtual host](https://serverfault.com/questions/667058/apache2-disable-catch-all-virtual-host/667069) that I should use `_default_` hosts as shown here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default.

Now I've created a */var/www/default/index.html* file and also a */etc/httpd/sites-available/default.conf* configuration with the following content:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
DocumentRoot /var/www/default
</VirtualHost>
```

while also creating its /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/default.conf symlink.

Now when I've tried testing my configuration with `httpd -t` I got the following error:

`httpd: Syntax error on line 355 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/default.conf: Too many levels of symbolic links`

I've also tried deleting the previously created default.conf file and tried to only add the:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
DocumentRoot /var/www/default
</VirtualHost>
```

at the beginning of the configuration file for the domain that was showing when visiting the IP of the webserver (the one that begins with an 'a').

All that with proper httpd restarts so the setting will apply. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something and not doing it right but not sure what is it.

Answer (score 0):

`Too many levels of symbolic links` strongly suggests that you have a loop of symbolic links, like

```
/etc/httpd/sites-available/default.conf -> ../sites-enabled/default.conf
```

and

```
/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/default.conf -> ../sites-available/default.conf
```

The output of `ls -l /etc/httpd/sites-*/default.conf` would show that.

Comment: I've deleted the old file and symlinks and started over so now I have `ls -l /etc/httpd/sites-*/default.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 71 Apr 29 22:30 /etc/httpd/sites-available/default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 39 Apr 29 22:31 /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/default.conf -> /etc/httpd/sites-available/default.conf` but even after restarting the httpd service I still get the same result when browsing the IP, the same a_something_domain shows up instead of the /var/www/default/index.html page as expected.